# What should I understand about optimization of Algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Time Complexity of Algorithm:

if two loops are not nested like

```
for I = 0 to N 
end
for J = 0 to N 
end
```

Then, the Time complexity of it becomes O(N+N).

And if both loop are nested then time complexity becomes O(N*N)

but what if two non-nested loops are inside a single one loop? like,

```
for K = 0 to N
  for I = 0 to N 
  end
  for J = 0 to N 
  end
end
```

**So Should I consider time complexity as O(N * (N + N)) or not?**

Actually, This came up in my mind while solving a leet code question in which I succeeded in solving the question on the first try with O(N^3) using a 3-nested loop. then I tried to solve a problem as above mentioned loop. inside a single loop, I used 2 non-nested loops.

**So did I optimise it or not?**

Comment: Is your question "Is O(2N^2) faster than O(N^3) as N increases? Then the answer is yes.

Comment: BTW `O(N+N)` is the same as `O(2*N)` and constant being summed or multiplied are ignored, so it is just `O(N)` - consequently `O(N*(N+N))` is just `O(N*N)` or `O(N²)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this technique optimizes your answer. You can think of it in layers. If you put a for into another for, it makes your algorithm n*n time complexity. However, they should be nested. If they are not nested, e.g. they are independent then it does not affect the total time complexity. For example:

```
for I = 0 to N 
end
for J = 0 to N 
end
```

is the same as in a for loop:

```
for K = 0 to N
  for I = 0 to N 
  end
  for J = 0 to N 
  end
end
```

So, the time complexity is O(n^2) for this algorithm and yes, you successfully optimized it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have optimized that because the first approach you got have had complexity of O(N^3) but in the next approach it became O(N*N) which is better than previous approach .